# Add text to specific lines of a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file "numbers" which consists of lines of numbers:

```
1 3 2
2 6 9
2 2 1
2 5 7
```

I want to add 0 0 0 to lines 2 and 3 using sed. That is, starting from the file "numbers", I want to generate the new file:

```
1 3 2
2 6 9 0 0 0
2 2 1 0 0 0
2 5 7
```

But I haven't been able to do it using sed. I know how to insert a line with:

```
sed '2i 0 0 0'
```

but I don't want to create new lines, just add that text to the already existing lines.

Comment: Use `{}`in the editor to markup the data, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should do what you want:

```
sed '2,3{s/$/ 0 0 0/}' file
```

For details pls read the manpage/infopage of sed, the "address" section.